# Tell JAXB binding compiler which elements to include

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Our services use wsdls with large one-size-fits-all schemas with complicated nested structures, IDREFs, schema imports etc.

Therefore no service will ever use all elements described in the schemas. Real services only use a relatively small subset of the schema. 
Generating JAXB beans from the schema produces unwieldy objects with many attributes that are mostly unused.

I know I can write my own JAXB beans and include only the interesting attributes. JAXB will ignore the rest during marshalling.

However, the structure of the schema and the xml response is complex enough to make me wish I could generate the JAXB beans and somehow tell the xjc which elements it should include.

Is that possible? Is there an xjc plugin which does that? Or ist there a JAXB implementation other than RI that can do it?

I know there are other techniques, such as an xpath based tolerant reader. But I want to know if JAXB can be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a [sample XJC plugin](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/make-a-surgical-strike-with-a-custom-xjc-plugin) which does something quite similar, it allows to suppress types on the package level and to manipulate classes and properties as shown below.

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="Person.xsd">
    <tpi:package removeClass="com.captech.person.Extra"/>
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Name']">
        <tpi:class getLastName="public synchronized" 
                    setFirstName="public synchronized"/>
        <tpi:class setLastName="public synchronized"/>
        <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='FirstName']">
            <tpi:property modifiers="private"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The blog article is also most useful because it shows how to debug a custom XJC plugin - this information was in Nabble formerly but the link on the JAXB2 page is broken now.

Comment: FWIW, here is the xjc plugin project: https://github.com/dschulten/jaxb2-tolerant-reader-plugin

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in XJC there's no built-in mechanism to include/exclude elements. There are, however a few tricks you can employ:

- Create an additional schema which imports your schema and define a few elements which reference only those elements/types you need. Then compile just your schema. XJC will (probably) just compile the required things. But I'm not sure.
- Try `jaxb:class/@ref` bindings to suppress generation of unnecessary classes.
- (Hardcore level.) A XJC plugin may manipulate the model and remove classe infos or property infos from it.

As far as I know, there is not other schema compiler for JAXB rather than XJC.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your proposals. It seems there is at least Moxy, but it does not seem to do what I want either: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/toc.htm

Comment: Looking into Moxy, they have xpath based bean mapping, which might prove useful for an xpath-based tolerant reader. However, that is not what I am after ATM. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts005.htm#CHDBFCAA

Comment: First suggestion does not work - all imports are resolved and compiled by xjc.

Comment: @dschulten MOXy does not provide an own schema compiler, does it?

Comment: I'll go for the custom XJC plugin and roll my own based on the sample project I've found. I voted for your answer anyway.